Elysia cron not stop when use one store with multiple path to stop
I have config elysia cron job for my schedule job. I have build using bun. I create utils for my job every time i want to have scheduler for my specific time to run. But when I call and separate the elysia only with unique path. The scheduler still running and not to stop the cron when i manually stop. below is my code:
import cron from '@elysiajs/cron';
import Elysia from 'elysia';
import { update as updateStatus, select as selectScheduler } from '../db/scheduler';
import { runK6 } from '../cmd/k6';

interface Scheduler {
    name: string;
    time: string;
    runningPath: any;
}

export const schedulerUtils = (schedule: Scheduler) => {
    const app = new Elysia();
    app.listen(3000);

    app.use(
        cron({
            name: schedule.name,
            pattern: schedule.time,
            run: async () => {
                const { platform, spec } = await getScheduler(schedule.name);
                console.log('start scheduler ', spec);
                if (platform === 'k6') {
                    await runK6(JSON.parse(spec as string));
                }
                console.log('stop scheduler ', spec);
            },
        })
    );

    app.get('/stop/:name', ({ params: { name }, store: { cron } }) => {
        cron[name].stop();
        updateStatus({ name, status: 0 });
        return `Stop heartbeat ${name}`;
    });
};

const getScheduler = async (name: string) => {
    const res = await selectScheduler(name);
    return res;
};

export const schedulerName = (spec: any) => {
    return (
        spec.projectName.toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ').join('_') +
        '_' +
        spec.name.toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ').join('_') +
        '_' +
        spec.path.toLocaleLowerCase().split('/').join('_')
    );
};

Any solution kindly suggestion or provided the tutorial how to using with elysia cron. Thank beforehand.
Hope the question will get the solution and how to use the elysia cron.
